# How to quantify the tree-like-ness of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-algorithms, tree

What are good measures of tree-like-ness of a graph and algorithms for calculating them?

Comment: There are many ways to measure the "tree-like-ness" of a graph. Which property of the tree would you like to preserve?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  Since trees don't have cycles, the number and length of cycles in a graph would seem to be a good negative measure of "tree-like-ness".  But (if we consider directed trees), uni-directionality also seems like an important characteristic of trees.  For instance, I would like a measure that says that a graph is _highly_ tree-like if it's a highly overlapping heterarchy with only two top-level nodes, and if directed, a particular dominant (but not necessarily universal) directionality.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition

Comment: Based on the comment, it sounds like you are interested in graphs that resemble an *arborescence*, i.e., a directed rooted tree in which all edges point away from the root node. (In general, a directed tree does not necessarily have any "dominant directionality".)